# I cannot find a solution to install ad-hoc ipadOS apps on MacOS with M1 CPU

Tags: ios, xcode, macos-big-sur, ipados

I have a problem i cannot find a answer for.

I want to deploy an ad-hoc certificated ipadOS app on my MacOS M1 machine.
Even better if its possible to debug the ipadOS app directly on my MacOS M1 machine.

The distributed app in app-store is easy to install on MacOS M1.

It does not seems possible to add MacOS M1 machine in App Provisioning Profile either, it only list ipad and phones. The "Include Mac Devices" under profiles in "Developer.apple.com -> Certificates, identifiers & Profiles" does not show previous added MAC UDID.

https://developer.apple.com/macos/iphone-and-ipad-apps/

Comment: Same problem. We need a workaround for that.